# How do I write this JavaScript loop for if?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

```
if (item + 600 === itemNew) {
  list.push(obj[i]);
} else {
  list.push({,
    Time: item
  });
  if (item + 1200 !== itemNew) {
    list.push({
      Time: item + 600
    });
    if (item + 1800 !== itemNew) {
      list.push({
        Time: item + 1200
      });
      if (item + 2400 !== itemNew) {
        list.push({
          Time: item + 1800
        });
        if (item + 3000 !== itemNew) {
          list.push({
            Time: item + 2400
          });
          if (item + 3600 !== itemNew) {
            list.push({
              Time: item + 3000
            });
            if (item + 4200 !== itemNew) {
              list.push({
                Time: item + 3600
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check and get the distance of two numbers relative to the value of 600. There is a loop that has a condition and must be traversed.
We check the previous value and if it is not the same as the next value, we add 600 to reach the condition

Comment: _"We check the previous value and if it is not the same as the next value, we add 600 to reach the condition"_ - Wrap that in a `while` loop (`for` would also work but imho `while` is the easier option) -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Have you heard of a while loop? Also, what if newItem isn't a multiple of 600 + the item?

Comment: What is `obj[i]`? Is there another loop outside? Please add some sample values for all the inputs like `item` and `itemNew` and expected output for it. Also, the first condition is `item + 600 === itemNew` while all the other are `!=`. What's the logic?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a normal `for` like this and creating an array with the times.

```js
const times = [600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3000, 3600, 4200];
const item = 5000;
const list = [];
const itemNew = 10000;
if (item + 600 === itemNew) {
  list.push(obj[i]);
} else {
  list.push({
    Time: item
  });
  for(let i = 1; i < times.length; ++i){
    if(item + times[i] !== itemNew){
      list.push({
        Time: item + times[i-1]
      });
    }
  }
}

console.log(list)
```

Or if you want it with a fixed interval you can do it having a maximum number of iterations and the multiplier like this:

```js
const item = 5000;
const list = [];
const itemNew = 10000;
const MAX_ITER = 7;
const multiplier = 600;
if (item + 600 === itemNew) {
  list.push(obj[i]);
} else {
  list.push({
    Time: item
  });
  for(let i = 2; i <= MAX_ITER; ++i){
    if(item + multiplier * i !== itemNew){
      list.push({
        Time: item + multiplier * (i - 1)
      });
    }
  }
}

console.log(list)
```

Comment: if there is a fixed interval between times, why not to make it part of the loop? for(let i=600; i<4800; i=i+600). I get impression most people don't even realize anymore what that whole first line in for loop is for and how is it different from foreach

Comment: @mikus True, I added the solution with a fixed interval

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```js
const item = 1000;
const itemNew = 5000;

const length = (itemNew - item - (itemNew - item) % 600) / 600;
const list = Array(length).fill(0).map((_, i) => ({
  Time: item + (i + 1) * 600
}));

console.log(list);
```

Comment: this needs at least an explanation, it's clear that the author is not familiar with most of the concepts in it